# Como exibir essa imagem no meu site em react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, imagem, conversão

Eu criei uma API rest pra me retornar uma imagem do meu bucket de S3 da amazon.
mas a imagem veio em um formato estranho e eu não consigo visualizar ela na minha pagina. O estranho é que quando eu realizo um get no postman a imagem aparece normalmente la na interface dele.

[image: Imagem de como aparece pra mim no console]

Comment: Verifique os headers, estou vendo que é application/json, mas deveria ser algo como isso: `Accept: image/png,image/svg+xml,image`
 depende da extensão do arquivo que está usando.

Comment: E como está lendo no seu código ? Poste o código que está fazendo.

Comment: Eu estou recebendo esse valor dentro de uma variável e queria passar ele pra dentro de uma tag <img> no react, mas se por isso no src ele carrega apenas uma imagem sem conteúdo

Comment: Esse campo data aí está com cara de uma imagem base64. Você tentou incluir a imagem dessa forma?

Comment: sim, tentei isso e dps todas as coisas possíveis, só sei que a imagem realmente está ai pq o postman ta exibindo ela normalmente

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido, eu apenas inclui "data:image/jpeg;base64," no inicio do conteúdo da data e o problema foi resolvido